# Async Pipe Error While Using Observable in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, typescript

I have pagination working in my Angular 2 app but am running into an issue where I'm getting an error re: the async pipe:

> Invalid argument '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

In the research I've done re: this error, it usually has to do with the fact that the async pipe expects an observable. This is confusing to me, because I am using an observable, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

First, here's my relevant view code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records | async | paginate: { id: 'stream', itemsPerPage: 15, currentPage: page, totalItems: total }">
```

This component is using an Input() from another component, like this:

```
@Input() records = [];
```

And here's "records" from that other component, which is an observable I'm subscribing to OnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.streamService.getBySection('section1')
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to explicitly declare this as type observable somewhere?

Comment: Presumably you mean to resolve the observable, paginate *then* iterate over the result? In which case `let record of (records | async | paginate: { ... })"`. But it appears that the observable is *already* resolved, by the `.subscribe`, in your class, and *not* exposed to the template as an observable.

Comment: How is that different from what I already have?

Comment: The parentheses clarify the order of operations, which can sometimes go awry. But the problem you have is that `records` *doesn't appear to be an observable*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async pipe expect an observable, not the resolved data.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.records = this.streamService.getByStage('section1');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess my thought is, is the "async" pipe redundant in this scenario then? No need to use it if I've already returned the result of the observable. Right?

Comment: That is correct. You can just remove the async, if you're not binding to an Observable, but a plain object.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks.